# Image-dropdown with callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to implement multiple dropdown fields that contain images, are positioned under each other, and that each have a JavaScript function assigned to them I can trigger by a button later on. Roughly saying like "oh, this and this and this got selected, press the button and trigger all the selected functions). The "add-to-cart" Cartjs.additem() function is working proper already, just not in this dropdown environment. I feel I got way over my head of course.

This is my code so far:

```js
$('#options').ddslick();
```

```css
<style class="cp-pen-styles">*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid__spans-25 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .grid__spans-25 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

#options,
.dd-select,
.dd-options {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.dd-selected-text,
.dd-option-text {
  line-height: 64px !important;
}

.dd-select {
  background: #fff !important;
  border-color: #d1d3d4 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.dd-selected {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="name"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="password"], select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  
  <div>
    <label for="options">Label</label>
    <select id="options" class="test">
      <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
</section>

 <section>
  
  <div class="grid__spans-25">
    <label for="options">Label</label>
    <select id="options" class="test">
      <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
</section>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script><script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ddslick/2.0/jquery.ddslick.min.js'></script>
```

My issue on hand is that a second added dropdown isn't working proper anymore.

I am hoping someone can push me in the right direction or recommend a solution that is easier to implement.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the dropdown select and button trigger working. The issue I am having now is that in order to get the pictures added to the dropdown, I need to include the following function:

```js
$('#options').ddslick();
```

This stops the dropdown from forwarding any value though, the forwarded value is shown as "undefined". Right now it's an either or.

Here is the whole code. The latter two would not prompt a value if I added $('#list1').ddslick(); or $('#list2').ddslick();

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">
    <section class="grid__spans-25">
  
  <div >
    <label for="options">Label</label>
    <select id="options" class="test">
      <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
</section>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item">
     <section class="grid__spans-25">
  <select id="list1">
   <option value="9107763265579">item 1</option>
    <option value="2">item 2</option>
    <option value="3">item 3</option>
</select>
  
</section>
  </li>
  
    <li class="flex-item">
     <section class="grid__spans-25">
       <select id="list2">
   <option value="1">item 1</option>
    <option value="2">item 2</option>
    <option value="3">item 3</option>
</select>
  
</section>
  </li>
  
</ul>

<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addToCart()">

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script><script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ddslick/2.0/jquery.ddslick.min.js'></script>
<script >

$('#options').ddslick();

</script>

<script>

function addToCart(){
 var school = document.getElementById('list1').value
  var item = document.getElementById('list2').value
  alert('school: '+school+' item: '+item)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to assign a different id to each instance.

```js
$('#options').ddslick();
$('#options2').ddslick();
```

```css
<style class="cp-pen-styles">*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid__spans-25 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .grid__spans-25 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

#options,
.dd-select,
.dd-options {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.dd-selected-text,
.dd-option-text {
  line-height: 64px !important;
}

.dd-select {
  background: #fff !important;
  border-color: #d1d3d4 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.dd-selected {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="name"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="password"], select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  
  <div>
    <label for="options">Label</label>
    <select id="options" class="test">
      <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
</section>

 <section>
  
  <div class="grid__spans-25">
    <label for="options2">Label</label>
    <select id="options2" class="test">
      <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
</section>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script><script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ddslick/2.0/jquery.ddslick.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: That solved the problem indeed, but now the fields are sized differently. Any idea? Also, how hard would you say it is to achieve the "add all selected to card" functionality if I have a working "add to card" JavaScript function?

Comment: 1. they are sized differently because the second wrapper-div has the class `grid__spans-25`. 2. not hard.

Comment: 1. I added the html section to the question further above but still have the same sizing issue. 2. Is there a buzzword that I can google to get a better idea how to achieve that?

Comment: 1. They look identical now. Might be a browser issue. 2. I didnt 100% understand what you mean by 'Add to card'. There are various ways to solve this. Depends on what you need.

Comment: Right now I have a js function that I trigger by clicking on a button on a product by product basis. This adds a particular product to a shopping cart. I think I know how to select an item from a drop down menu and trigger a function (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/hYY6X/). What I don't know is how to trigger all functions that correspond to multiple dropdown selections with the click of one button.

Comment: It would work like this: 1. Dropdown 1, select product 5 >> Dropdown 2, select product 4 >> click on button and add product 5 and product 4 to the shopping cart.

Comment: @FatTwin You can do this by reading out the `value` of each `select` element. http://jsfiddle.net/r8q0qk23/

Comment: Niiice. Thanks! I will try to get it working that way. Let me get back to you in a few.

Comment: Manuel, thanks so much, I was able to get it to work, but one issue persists. Please see Update section.

Comment: @FatTwin you will need to get the selected value via `$('#list1').data('ddslick')`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have an affect on the ddslick part, no images are shown, but I am still able to output the right values. I just have to add this code under the $('#options').ddslick(); correct?

Comment: @FatTwin no, you have to replace the `document.getElementById('list1').value` with it.

Comment: Can't figure it out, but thanks a lot. You helped me a great deal :)